# How to write equations?

Tags: support, mathjax

I want to input equations with special characters in a question, is there some way to do that? Is there like some program or some code to do it?

Comment: See if [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136/is-it-possible-to-explain-how-to-use-latex-in-questions-answers-in-the-how-to) (and links within) helps you.

Answer (score 3):

We use LaTeX here (powered by MathJax).

I have a small tutorial [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) on using LaTeX in posts. There are more links below.

[This tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/117/24293) is also pretty nice. We have a short FAQ entry [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation)